# Invalid Value Error when Searching for Google Drive files based on multiple property values

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to search based on multiple property values separated by boolean:

```
"properties has { key='additionalID' and value='someValue' and visibility='PUBLIC' } 
or 
properties has { key='additionalID' and value='someOtherValue' and visibility='PUBLIC' }"
```

as described in [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) to the `q` parameter in [drive.files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

I keep getting an invalid value error.

Comment: I just used this query in the [APIs Explorer](http://goo.gl/IaUB1V) and it worked without error. Can you try again?

Comment: Thank you, @EricKoleda. It works. My silly mistake was not assigning visibility='public' to my keys to begin with. I will leave this SOF question up for others.